# puppeteer reference error in page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Hi im learning puppeteer headless browser, but there is something that i dont understand

1) why i cant use a variable as a selector?

this works

```
  const lastUpdate = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > strong').textContent);
```

but this give me reference error LAST_UPDATE SELECTOR is not defined

```
const LAST_UPDATE_SELECTOR = 'body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > strong';
const lastUpdate = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(LAST_UPDATE_SELECTOR).textContent);
```

What im doing wrong? maybe there is something new that i need to learn

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass the variable to the `evaluate` function as an argument.

```
const selector = '#someSelector';

// 2. read the passed data
const lastUpdate = await page.evaluate((selector) => { 

  // 3. use it here
  document.querySelector(selector).textContent, 

// 1. Pass it here
}, selector);
```

What's going on?

`.evaluate` accepts two arguments,`pageFunction`, and the rest are serialized `args`. When running the pageFunction, it passes the arguments to that, and then it becomes available inside the browser context.

Learn more about it on the puppeteer [API docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

Comment: this worked, how is called this way of passing arguments? i want to learn more about it Thanks!

Comment: `Evaluation failed: SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` -- this is what I get following this example.